# Data-link opening too many tabs Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I was wondering whether anyone knew why my data-link might be opening four tabs of the same link in a single click?

At the moment I have the following loop in my rails view:

```
<% @generals.each do |general| %>
    ...
        <div class="product" data-link="<%= general.url %>" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'General', 'Click', '<%= general.title %>', <%= general.position.to_f %>]);">
            ...Some Content....
        </div>
    ...
<% end %>
```

This loop is currently generating 5 products on a page with the div class `.product`

I then have a basic coffeescript command of:

```
$ ->
  $('.product[data-link]').click -> window.open 'http://' + $(this).data('link');
```

I am under the impression that this should work but it doesn't seem to. Any advice people have would be great!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you are closing your divs. That would cause each div to be nested within the previous one and could cause this behavior especially since you have not stopped propagation of the event.

Comment: Sorry that's an error by me typing it into Stackoverflow, I have amended above. Any other ideas? :)